# How can I create a window for headless testing on nodejs?

Tags: node.js, backbone.js

Why can I do to create a window so it doesn't throw this error?

```js
throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
Error: jQuery requires a window with a document
```

Here's my app.js file.

```js
var Backbone  = require('backbone');
var jquery    = require('jquery');
var jsdom     = require('jsdom');

var JournalView = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#board',
  initialize: function() {
    this.render();
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html("Hello, world!");
  },
});

var journalView = new JournalView();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `window` from jsdom

here is an example: http://artsy.github.io/blog/2013/06/14/writing-headless-backbone-tests-with-node-dot-js/

```
jsdom.env({
  html: "<html><body></body></html>",
  done: function(errs, window) {
    global.window = window;
    // ...
    callback();
  }
});
```